# Bazel error: "No test targets were found, yet testing was requested"

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, magenta

I have a small assignment where I used TensorFlow to create music:

https://github.com/tensorflow/magenta

When I run the code `--- bazel test //magenta:all`
I get the following error:

```
WARNING: /home/admin/.cache/bazel/_bazel_admin/fb30f33370a5b97d4f9b1dde06f8f344/external/protobuf/protobuf.bzl:90:19: Variables HOST_CFG and DATA_CFG are deprecated in favor of strings "host" and "data" correspondingly.
WARNING: /home/admin/.cache/bazel/_bazel_admin/fb30f33370a5b97d4f9b1dde06f8f344/external/protobuf/protobuf.bzl:96:28: Variables HOST_CFG and DATA_CFG are deprecated in favor of strings "host" and "data" correspondingly.
INFO: Found 2 targets and 0 test targets...
INFO: Elapsed time: 4.977s, Critical Path: 0.66s
ERROR: No test targets were found, yet testing was requested.
```

Answer (score 8):

When you run

```
bazel test magenta:all
```

This means "execute all *_test rules defined in file magenta/BUILD.
When I look at that file, there are no tests defined there.
https://github.com/tensorflow/magenta/blob/master/magenta/BUILD

You should try:

```
bazel test magenta/...
```

This translates to all things that are included in magenta folder, including other packages. For more information, please see:
https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/command-line-reference.html